# How to disable Tensorflow's multi-threading?

Tags: tensorflow

I'm running Tensorflow programs with a simulator that does not support multi-threading. I changed intra_op_parallelism_threads to 1 in tensorflow/core/common_runtime/local_device.cc at line 38 but I still get runtime errors as soon as the treading starts. My guess is the multi-theading setup is still there. Is it possible to disable multi-threading?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot, as of early 2017, disable tensorflow's multithreading.

Comment: This answer is still valid in Oct 2020.